# Frozen Corned Beef left out to thaw,

Tags: food-safety

in cold basement approximately 40-45 degrees, it was completely frozen about 3 lb. brisket. Discovered it 24 hours later. It was cold to touch, and completely thawed. Still in original vacuum packaging from store. Will this be safe to cook?

Comment: Either that, or: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer This is a weird in-between question, though...

Comment: Is this an actual corned beef, as in salt treated, or a brisket you plan to make into corned beef yourself?

Comment: If this is shelf stable food, as in cured meat which is always safe to eat when left at room temperature, then disregard the duplicate. But if it says "requires refrigeration" at the package, standard food safety rules apply, see the linked question. In any case, it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

**I'd be fine with it.** Salt is a preservative, and it was still cold to the touch - not the same as if it had spent 24 hours in a 70 degree F environment, or a 40 degree C environment.

The default mantra for this site is to **throw everything away.** If you or someone you are feeding actually is immune compromised, this makes sense - if not, it's a rather extreme view, but that's the way the wind blows here, so that's the advice you can expect to see upvoted.

Comment: I upvoted this one because I'd still eat it.

Comment: @duncan This is exactly why the site only allows the interpretation of "food safety" as "safe according to the FDA rules". If everybody votes "yes" or "no" depending on whether they'd eat it, it is by definition a poll question and we'd have to close it outright.

Comment: Yeah, the view sometimes seems extreme, but it is the *only* way to keep everyone within the bounds of potential risk defined by much smarter experts. Better that we recommend you toss a suspect food than for someone to get seriously sick just because someone on the Internet said it was probably okay.

Answer (score 0):

Technically; corned beef is so highly salted and preserved; it would probably be fine.

That said; 40-140 is considered the danger zone for food; bacteria / food borne illness can grow.

For the 10 or 15 bucks lost; i would Chuck it and avoid the risk of food poisoning.